# Youtube API Error 402: Payment Required

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to use Youtube API on a dedicated server for **the first time** but I have this error.

[image]

I read the FAQ https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#http-error-429-too-many-requests-or-402-payment-required
but as I said I use it for the **first time**...

So how to "unban" my server IP? I would not be able to do a Captcha since it's a dedicated server and not my bowser.

Comment: I tried to use --proxy and I get an error "connection refused" and I tried with a cookie file and it doesn't work too.

Comment: Based on this YouTube [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/core_errors#PAYMENT_REQUIRED), the error 402 means that the requested operation requires some kind of payment from the authenticated user.

Check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107455/getting-402-payment-required-using-youtubes-iframe-api-to-embed-videos) for more information.

Comment: When your IP, or the ip-range is blocked you may have to solve a Captcha. The easiest way would be to use a working proxy. The hard way: Install a VNC Server on your server, or use your server as a proxy for your desktop and run the captcha and import the cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that youtube-dl API bloks IPv6 IPs from OVH servers. I had to force the IPv4 and it solved it.